# MUI Input Base Outline on Hover

Tags: material-ui

I have this MUI outlined input. When I focus on it, there is this blue line which appears. How can I remove it?

[image]

Below is my code

```
 <OutlinedInput
              size="small"
              placeholder={`Search ${filter.name.toLowerCase()}`}
              value={searchTerm[filter.name] || ''}
              onChange={(e) => handleSearchChange(e, filter.name)}
              fullWidth
              sx={{
                height: 32,
                mt: 1,
                ".MuiInputBase-input": {
                  outline: "none !important",
                  ".Mui-focused": {
                    outline: "none !important",
                  }
                }
              }}
              endAdornment={
                <InputAdornment position="end">
                  <IconButton
                    aria-label="clear filter"
                    onClick={() => setSearchTerm(prev => ({ ...prev, [filter.name]: "" }))}
                    edge="end"
                    size="small"
                  >
                    <CloseIcon sx={{ fontSize: 20 }} />
                  </IconButton>
                </InputAdornment>
              }
            />
```

Comment: What browser you are using? this blue border outside the input shouldn't appear on OutlinedInput, you likely have conflicting css from outside mui. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/naughty-rosalind-4d8ljj

Comment: I'm using google chrome